# Glassfish v3.1: LifecycleListener vs. Startup.Listener

Tags: listener, startup, glassfish-3, lifecycle

How to correctly call my code when Glassfish v3.x is `READY` or going to `SHUTDOWN`?

I was succesfully using lifecycle listener on glassfish v2.x. 
Unfortunatelly, this interface is marked as `DEPRECATED` in Glassfish v3.x. A new interface `Startup` is recomended instead but I don't know how to use it and could not find any useful documentation or examples. Could you please point me to how use it?

Answer (score 0):

You want what's called a lifecycle module. [Chapter 12, Developing Lifecycle Listeners](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beamc.html#scrolltoc) is a good place to start. This explains the available events and when they fire. Once you have your class codded and ready to go this [blog entry](http://blogs.oracle.com/pblaha/entry/how_to_implement_cron_in) will explain how to deploy the module to GlassFish using the admin console..